# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (doctype?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. FireBug has shown me this error:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
$.post(('<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The respective code would be:

```
$('#botonGuardarIngreso').on('click', function(){
        var html = $(this).html();
        $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> Cargando...');
        $.post(('{{ path('editar_proceso', {'id': procesado}) }}'), $('form').serialize(), function(data){
            $('#botonGuardarIngreso').html(html);
            if(data.exito){
                exito('El proceso disciplinario fue modificado exitosamente');
                window.location = '{{ path('index_proceso') }}';
            }else{
                error(data.errores, 'Errores, por favor reviselos', 15000);
            }
        }, 'json');
    });
```

Comment: As you can see from weird syntax highlight, error is in `$.post(('{{ path('editar_proceso'`

Comment: what do you meant by this? '{{ path('index_proceso') }}'

Comment: So why is the include giving you an html document and not an url?

Comment: Use different quotes when nesting, `$.post(("{{ path('editar_proceso', {'id': procesado}) }}")`

Answer (score 1):

I guess `{{ path('editar_proceso', {'id': procesado}) }}` generate a template.

Remove `\n` in this template or replace it with `\\n` (backslash at the end, before new line).